# AngularJS Filter After One Time Binding in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I was wondering if it is possible to one-time bind a variable in an ng-repeat directive and then filter on that variable.

My code right now unfortuantely performs a one-time binding of the variable AFTER filtering has been performed, though I need the binding to be done BEFORE filtering is performed.

Here is my code:

```html
<div flex="20" ng-repeat="item in ::vm.items | filter: vm.itemSearch
    | limitTo: vm.query.limit : (vm.query.page -1) * vm.query.limit">

</div>
```

Keep in mind that vm.items is an array that could potentially get to 20,000 elements in side, hence the need for one-time binding.

The filters are used for both searching and pagination. What I'd like to be able to do is something like the following:

```html
<div flex="20" ng-repeat="item in (::vm.items) | filter: vm.itemSearch
    | limitTo: vm.query.limit : (vm.query.page -1) * vm.query.limit">

</div>
```

However, this is not valid AngularJS syntax due to the following error:

Syntax Error: Token ':' not a primary expression at column 2 of the expression.

Does anyone have a way of getting around this limitation?

Comment: I suggest give a look at the module [Bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce) for high performance binding in AngularJS

Comment: I've tried using that and it made no difference sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's actually possible. Any one time bound value won't change after applying filtering.

You should only pass the filtered result to your `ng-repeat`. Performancewise the `| limitTo` does all the trick. You should put that to a method inside your controller - I think your error comes from the `: or-operator` there.

Comment: The error comes from this (::vm.items). What I need is to have the array available in the HTML-markup without it being in the Angular digest cycle.

Comment: You should remove those brackets here. I also think, that filtering the array in the controller and passing the filtered result to ng-repeat and | limitTo should just be fine.